# Constructors of pathlib.Path subtypes

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to sub-type a `pathlib.Path` with an extra constructor assert as follows

```
import pathlib

class TempDirPath(type(pathlib.Path())):
    def __init__(self, path):
        assert not os.path.isabs(path), "Temporary directory path must be relative"
        super(TempDirPath, self).__init__(path)
```

But this errors as

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

Why does `super(TempDirPath, self)` evaluate to `object`. Shouldn't it be `type(pathlib.Path())`. I have tried different proposed solutions on the web without any progress. What do do?

Comment: To take the discovery you already made in your answer and put it in relation to part of your question: The reason it says `object.__init__()` isn't because `super(TempDirPath, self)` evaluates to anything surprising, it's because none of the classes in the inheritance graph implement `__init__()`, so the implementation it finally runs is that of `object`. And, of course, `object.__init__()` is too generic to take any parameters.

Comment: *Note:* You don't have to use `super(TempDirPath, self)` if you're on Python 3. [In a class definition, the compiler accepts `super()` and fills in the missing pieces](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: After some digging it turned out that

```
class TempDirPath(type(pathlib.Path())):
    def __init__(self, path):
        assert not self.is_absolute(), "Temporary directory path '{}' must be relative".format(self)
```

solved it because `Path` is initialized in the `__new__` member. It has no `__init__` member.